# SQL join with the same table with different select

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, where-clause

I have a table tablename with columns col1-col10. **Not every row has col4 populated**, but every row has col1, col2, col3 populated.
I want to get all {col1, col2, col3} tuples for when col4 satisfies a condition, then get all rows that match the tuple {col1, col2, col3} from tablename.

I am not sure if I should be using inner join or left join or something else? ( I think both inner and left join should give me same result)
The query below gives me a syntax error "mismatched input AS". What is the correct way to write this query?

```
select col1, col2, col3
from tablename 
where col4 >= 1000 AS A
INNER JOIN
(select *
FROM tablename) AS B
ON A.col1 = B.col1 AND A.col2 = B.col2 A.col3 = B.col3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t1
    where 
        t1.col1 = t.col1 
        and t1.col2 = t.col2 
        and t1.col3 = t.col3 
        and t1.col4 >= 1000
)
```

Comment: what is the meaning of `select 1` in this query?

Comment: @user1745995: `exists` just checks if the subquery returns some row (no matter the content), so we don't need it to return something - hence `select 1`. It is just a convention, you would use `select *` or `select 0`, it would not change the results.

Comment: Is this the join equivalent :